# ACC0 and the majority gate

Tags: complexity-theory

I am missing something obvious [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACC0#Computational_power). Does ACC0 reach a ceiling AC0[m] with m being constant?

By [another](https://complexityzoo.net/Complexity_Zoo:A#acc0) description, ACC0 can use any m, which can trivially test modulus gates from [n/2,n] over all inputs. Any modulus active in that range indicates MAJ returns true, implementable as an OR over the current range of gates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not reach a constant ceiling, but the modulo gate cannot depend on the input's length, e.g. $\bmod n/2$ gates are not allowed. You must decide on the constants while constructing the circuit, independently of the input/input size. See the definition in Arora and Barak's book, where they first define $ACC0(m_1,...,m_k)$ which corresponds to circuits with $\bmod m_1,...,\bmod m_k$ gates, and then define $ACC0$ as the union of $ACC0(m_1,...,m_k)$ over all integer $k$-tuples.

Comment: Thanks. Does this mean that the nonuniform circuit can solve MAJ?

Comment: Well we're still in the nonuniform model, it's just that the mod circuits of the entire family are bounded. If you allow $\bmod k$ gates where $k\le n$ then yes, you could compute majority as you described.

Comment: A single mod m gate, n ≤ m would be sufficient. The lower range of [n/2,n] can be imitated by feeding a corresponding number of additional inputs set high. I may still misunderstand; Emphasizing the largest modular gate available removes restriction on the length of those k-tuples. This is why I focused on AC0[m].

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. There is no restriction on the length of the $k$-tuples, the union is also over $k$, i.e. $ACC^0=\bigcup\limits_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\bigcup\limits_{m_1,...,m_k\in\mathbb{N}}ACC^0(m_1,...,m_k)$.

Comment: Definitely my bad for not being clear. If mod circuits are bounded, does that mean bounded by k, or by m_k (I am assuming the k-tuple strictly increases)? Either one unbounded gives a fairly simple design for MAJ, so I guess the answer is both?

Comment: Looking at the union above, the mod gates of a specific circuit family in $ACC^0$ are clearly bounded (the family lies in the union for some $k$ and $m_1,...,m_k$).